# Does weak convergence of two independent sequences of random processes imply weak convergence of the couple sequence?

Tags: statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

I consider sequences of random processes in the Skorohod space. Let $F_n$ and $G_n$ converge weakly to F and G, respectively, in $D[-\infty,\infty]$ endowed with the supnorm. I suppose that this implies that $(F_n,G_n)$ converges weakly to $(F,G)$ in $D[-\infty,\infty]^2$ with the $\max\{\|\|,\|\|\}$ norm. 
My attempts:
Using the portmanteau lemma I tried to check that $\liminf_{n\to\infty} P((X_n,G_n)\in U)\geq P((F,G)\in U)$ for all U open in $D[-\infty,\infty]^2$. Let first U be a product of open sets in $D[-\infty,\infty]$, $U=U_1\times U_2$:
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}P((F_n,G_n)\in U)=\liminf_{n\to\infty}P(F_n\in U1)P(G_n\in U2)\geq P(F\in U1)P(G\in U2)=P((F,G)\in U)
$$
(I applied the portmanteau lemma on the componentwise convergence and used the independence of the processes for each n and of the limit processes).
For general U and disjoint unions of product sets with $\bigcup{U_{i,1}\times U_{i,2}}\subset U$, we have:
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}P((F_n,G_n)\in U)\geq\liminf_{n\to\infty}P((F_n,G_n)\in \bigcup{U_{i,1}\times U_{i,2}})\geq \liminf\sum P((F_n,G_n)\in U_{i,1}\times U_{i,2})\geq \sum P((F,G)\in U_{i,1}\times U_{i,2})=P((F,G)\in \bigcup U_{i,1}\times U_{i,2})
$$
hence
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}P((F_n,G_n)\in U)\geq \sup P((F,G)\in \bigcup U_{i,1}\times U_{i,2})
$$
where the sup goes over disjoint unions of product sets that are subsets of U.
I assume that this last term is equal to $P((F,G)\in U)$. I know that $D[-\infty,\infty]^2$ is not separable, however I still have hope for that to be true, as we are allowed to take product sets not only of balls, but of general open sets in $D[-\infty,\infty]$ which might damp the lack of seperability. 
Any ideas? Or am I simply wrong?